# eror on terminal command for truffle ( development )

Tags: truffle

bro im stuck in here any fix for that :

```
truffle(development)> balance = await token.balance0f('0x4689734E466F746CBBfCD7C8b451b4143215887D')
```

this is bug

```
( Uncaught TypeError: token.balance0f is not a function      
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:13 )
```

i hope you can fixed for that bugs